# Shortening Bash output command

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Is there a more efficient way to output a command than this:

```
whereis python > test.txt;date >> test.txt;who >> test.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
{ whereis python; date; who; } > test.txt
```

EDIT:

The `{...}` notation instructs `bash` to launch these commands in the current shell, rather than use a subshell as would be the case if the `(...)` notation was used. It is slightly more efficient as it avoids creating a new process.

If you want to temporarily change the environment (working directory, variables etc) for the comamnds, though, the `(...)` notation is simpler to use, since you don't have to manually revert all changes afterwards:

```
( whereis python; date; who ) > test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(whereis python; date; who) >test.txt
```